# CSS solid border around image don't work on tablet?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">This is a title</h3><br />
    <img src="images/site/image.jpg" style="border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;" height="333" width="493" />
```

and my image get well a small border around when using any kind of browser PC but not when I look with Ipad or Galaxy Note 10.1. When using smartphone such Iphone or Galaxy Note 3 no problem...

I'm supposed to use a different code planned for tablet ? If yes I did not found something about on google.

Any clue ?

Comment: I tried `<img src="pixel.gif" style="border: 1px solid #bbb;" width="300" height="250" />` on a iPad1 with iOS 5 and a iPad4 with iOS 7, it's working fine. Can you show more code?

Comment: Really ? So strange.. I don't have more code to show. My page contain only the code I published above.. I tested with my own physical Tablet and also with browserstack.com.

Comment: I also tested this code on my galaxy tab and it works even in native browser. Try to increase your border width, maybe you cannot see it, because of the picture. http://jsfiddle.net/hnuWn/1/

Comment: I made just right now also a test here http://jsfiddle.net/JGNYP/1/ and I confirm I can see now the border on my Tablet. So it seem I have a conflict somewhere. In fact when I say I don't have more code is not totally true because is a CMS page. Probably the template of my CMS cause some issue which make hidden the border in some case. Well is not a big deal..I don't have time to investigate more deeper just for that. thank for your test.

Answer (score -1):

CSS support is not consistent among different browsers and platforms. But there are workarounds. Sometimes you can express the same rules differently to obtain the same effect. In this case you can try declaring the border properties separately:

```
border-color: #bbbbbb; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;
```